# How to properly mock a function returned by a React hook, inside a module that contains multiple hooks?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a custom React hook file that looks like this (contains multiple hook functions), and I want to mock the handleSubmit that is returned by only one of the hook

```js
// useHook.js

export function useFirstHook() {
  // calling useStates...
  const [ state, setState ] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = () => {}

  return [ state, {handleSubmit}]

}
export function useSecondHook() { ... }
export function useThirdHook() { ... }
```

```js
// Component.js
import {useFirstHook} from './useHooks'

export function Component () {
  const [ state, {handleSubmit} ] = useFirstHook()
  return <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click Me</button>
}
```

I want to be able to test my button works, and that it will invoke handleSubmit when clicked. This is what I have so far.

```js
//tests.js

let submitMk = jest.fn()

jest.mock('../../usehooks', () => ({
  useFirstHook: () => {
    return [ '', {
      handleSubmit: submitMk 
    }]

  }

}))

test('onClick should be triggered when button is clicked',  () => {
  render(<Component />)

  screen.getByText('Click Me').click()
  expect(submitMk.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1)

})
```

But it will fail saying that the mocked function is not called. Which makes me think there must have been a mistake in the mocking process.

What is the proper way to mock `handleSubmit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in question should work in theory. The issue I had, (that was completely left out from the question) and that I want to remind everyone who is having issues with `jest.mock` not mocking modules correctly is that this needs to be done at the most top level (module level). Putting the `jest.mock` inside a `beforeAll()` block, or a `beforeEach()` will give issues.

**On a side note** if you are trying to mock a custom hook, placing the `jest.mock` on the top level, means that the hook would be called at the top/module level, so no further issues there :)